# Atom is always opening developer console.How could i disable it

Tags: text-editors, console, atom-editor, google-chrome-devtools

I installed atom text editor and compeleted a project.But now,i cant open my project.Its always opening chrome dev tools/debugging console in atom.I uninstalled it and install is again.But its not opening text editor.Its opening debugging console over and over.

Comment: Does the problem persist when you launch Atom in safe mode (e.g. `atom --safe`)? In that case it's likely a third-party package responsible for that kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I too was having the exact same issue of Atom opening in dev tools and after executing
 `atom --safe` as suggested by [@idleberg](https://superuser.com/users/195953/idleberg) my Atom text editor finally opened as expected. Now the issue becomes how to figure out which 3rd Party App is causing this issue.